# How to prove two eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue of a matrix cannot be orthogonal to each other.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, symmetric-matrices

First, let x, y be the right and left eigenvectors

let λ1 and λ2 be **different** eigenvalues

So, I can consider Ax=λ1x and then I will find the result and (λ2-λ1)y*x=0

Since λ2 is not equal to λ1, y*x=0 => Orthogonal

However, how to prove  two eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue of a matrix cannot be orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Hmm. take the identity matrix and any two orthogonal vectors.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Take the identity matrix. Every vector is an eigen vector corresponding to eigen value $1$!

Answer (score 0):

It is false. Take for instance the identity matrix. Every vector is an eigenvector, and you can choose lots and lots of orthogonal pairs of vectors.